# Webs.GetWeb() returns 401-Access Denied error for user with View Only Permission level

Tags: permissions, web-services

We have a Sharepoint 2013 farm in our labs with which we would be interacting using the MOSS SOAP services and generating reports for a client.

To facilitate this, we create a user **JohnDoe** who has **View Only** permission level on the target site for which the report is to be generated say **MySite**.

When we invoke the `Webs.GetWebCollection()` method in the `Webs.asmx` service, we get a **401 - Access Denied** and our program aborts. If we change the permission level of **JohnDoe** to 
**Contribute**, then we are all good.

What permissions are needed for **Webs.GetWebCollection()** to be invoked successfully?.

By the way - a browser running under the context of **JohnDoe** can navigate to **MySite** and fetch the WSDL for **Webs.asmx** successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's not exactly your case, take a look to this link, cos I think is related with your error: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chandru/archive/2010/10/15/sharepoint-2007-getwebcollection-webs-asmx-does-not-return-webs-based-on-a-user-permission.aspx.

Regarding the link, it seems that the method GetWebCollection, actually returns all the Webs, doesn't matter if the user has permissions or not, so, I can imagine that if the user doesn't have permissions, the error is expected. The article has a workarround creating a custom service, that I don't know if it's possible in your case.

Anyway, considering is SP 2013, I suggest you to use the CSOM instead of calling the old webservice. In this case, you can use the method:

```
Web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getsubwebsforcurrentuser(v=office.15).aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: I agree with you. Just as you were probably typing out this post, I came across the exact MSDN link that you mentioned. In addition there is one more link L:http://wssdevelopment.blogspot.in/2008/01/access-denied-when-using-spsiteallwebs.html which is related. Thank you very much for the note.It solves my query.